# MongooseError: Operation `tweets.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mern

I am trying to make a simple CRUD app using mongodb and express, but when I am making the create method I keep getting this error, I have tried everything. changing the DNS server, i even set the database access to allow from anywhere. but it still doesn't seem to work.

For the internet, I use hotspot tethering from data celluler on my phone to connect to the internet.

the server could run but when I try to send some post request using postman to http://localhost:5000/v1/api/tweets/ its not sending any response only errors

here are the codes.

MAIN - index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const router = require('./routes')
//const { connectToDb } = require('./config/db')

const app = express()
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded());

app.use((req, res, next) => { //set headers
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*')
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type')
    next();
})

app.use('/v1/api/', router )

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
.then(app.listen(process.env.PORT, ()=>{ console.log(`Server is listening on port ${process.env.PORT}`)}))
.catch(err => console.log(err))
```

main router

```
const router = require("express").Router()
const tweets = require('./tweets')

router.use('/tweets', tweets)

module.exports = router
```

tweets router

```
const router = require('express').Router()
const { tweet } = require('../controllers')

router
.post('/', tweet.createTweet)


module.exports = router
```

tweets controller

```
const Tweet = require('../schemas/TweetSchema')

module.exports = {
    createTweet : (req, res, next) => {
        const author = req.body.author
        const text = req.body.text

        const Tweets = new Tweet({
            author,
            text
        })

        Tweets.save()
        .then(result => {
            res.status(201).json({
                desc: 'success'
            })
            next()
        })
        .catch((err)=>console.log(err))

        
    },
}
```

Tweet Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema
const TweetSchema = new Schema({
    author: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    text: {
        type: String, 
        required: true
    }
},{
    timestamps: true
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("Tweet", TweetSchema)
```

the error message

```
MongooseError: Operation `tweets.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/mnt/d/Programming/Web Development/twimern/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:149:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)
Error: queryTxt ETIMEOUT twimern.xdzes.mongodb.net
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (node:dns:213:19) {
  errno: undefined,
  code: 'ETIMEOUT',
  syscall: 'queryTxt',
  hostname: 'twimern.xdzes.mongodb.net'
}
```

Thank you, my bad if the code is pretty hard to read. I hope you can help me out.

Comment: you dont response on /tweets you shoud define function to return data

Comment: The routes for the /tweets are defined on the `tweets router`, and it linked to the  createTweet method on the controller that sends response after the Tweets.save(). It gives the error that I sent whenever i tried to send a post request, though.

Comment: so you encounter timeout in save ?

Comment: I think so.. because I tried running the app without the Tweets.save() and it ran smoothly.

Comment: maybe your connection to mongo db has been failed?

Comment: I dont know exactly, but the .then() callback on mongoose.connect could run.

Comment: instead of save get data from monggose to check connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE :
I changed my internet from hotspot tethering using my phone to a normal WiFi connection. And it solved the problem. I don't know exactly why this happened but the error is gone now. Thanks.